# unter anderem / unter anderen

Tags: word-usage

Was ist richtig? *unter anderem* oder *unter anderen* oder beides?

Ein Beispiel:

> In vielen Sprachen (**unter anderem** / **unter anderen** Englisch und Französisch) ist es zwingend erforderlich, dass ein Wort die Position des Subjekts einnimmt.

Comment: Ich bin versucht, den Satz [in der Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletivum) jetzt einfach mal zu *unter anderen* zu „korrigieren“ ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*unter anderem* (*u. a.*) ist in diesem Fall richtig, neben den angeführten Beispielen Englisch und Französisch existieren noch weitere in Frage kommende Sprachen.

*unter anderen* kommt hingegen bei Sätzen wie *Ich wollte einmal unter anderen Menschen sein* zur Anwendung. Die beiden Formen werden so oft vertauscht, dass der Duden *unter anderem* in der *[Liste der rechtschreiblich schwierigen Wörter](http://www.duden.de/schwierige-woerter#u)* führt.

Comment: "*... neben den angeführten Beispielen Englisch und Französisch existieren noch weitere ...*" ich halte diesen Nachsatz für irreführend., da es sich bei `unter anderem` ja eben genau **nicht** um einen Plural handelt.

Comment: @alk Ich habe die Verwendung für interessierte Lerner erläutern wollen. Wie viele Elemente die Aufzählung hinter *unter anderem* umfasst, ist nachrangig.

Comment: Die Seite im Duden für _[unter anderem](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unter_anderem)_ gibt nichts an über eine mögliche Verwechselung mit _unter anderen_; dort ist kein Eintrag für _unter andern_. Aber [die Antwort von Carten S](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9363/20357) referiert an http://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/57345/sbj/unter-anderem-unter-anderen/, wo Duden auf CD zitiert wird in dem Sinne daß _unter anderen_ gebraucht wird wenn es um Personen geht.

Answer (score 4):

Da „die Sprachen“ im Plural ist, ist „unter anderen“ keineswegs falsch. Die Beispiele [hier](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/unter+anderen.html) belegen dies. Die anderen Antworten hier hingegen belegen, dass auch „unter anderem“, obwohl grammatisch nicht logisch, akzeptabel ist, da es als feststehende Wendung empfunden wird.

Siehe auch [hier](http://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/57345/sbj/unter-anderem-unter-anderen/), wo der Duden zitiert wird.

Answer (score 3):

`unter` wird mit dem Dativ benutzt.

Im Zusammenhang mit `Das Andere` (siehe OP), was Einzahl ist, ergibt sich also `unter dem Anderen` kurz `unter anderem`. (Warum das nun klein geschrieben werden muss weiss ich nicht.)

`unter anderen` ist die Variante für einen Plural:

> Er fand nix unter dem Stein, und unter anderen<sup>*1</sup> fand sich auch nix.

`Die Anderen` ist Plural, gemeint sind nämlich `die Steine`.

---

Zusammenfassend ist der Lösungsweg zur Antwort die Deklination mit Dativ Singular von `Das Andere` zzgl. einer Prise Gross-/Kleinschreiberegeln, nach denen ja aber nicht gefragt war - zum Glück ;-)

---

<sup>*1: Und hier wird auch klein geschrieben?</sup>

Comment: Es wird klein geschrieben, weil es in diesem Fall keinen "substantivischen Charakter" zur Hervorhebung gibt, siehe [Duden, Regel 77](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#K77)

Comment: @lejonet: Danke! Bitte schau mal auf mein Update.

Comment: schön :)... "Unter dem ersten Stein fand er einen Käfer. Unter anderen unter anderem Sand."

Comment: @Emanuel: Great, für solche Spielchen liebe ich diese Sprache.

Answer (score 1):

Im Beispielsatz ist *unter anderem* korrekt:

> In vielen Sprachen (unter anderem Englisch und Französisch) ist es zwingend erforderlich, dass ein Wort die Position des Subjekts einnimmt.